# Got the brake shoe to Kekkabah, Atchisons all dead - mission not resolved?

Tags: wasteland-2

RNC - I've gone through the mission without reading any FAQ. 
So I didnt go the peace way. It made sense to me to pick the Topekans side since they had the train itself.
I've rescued Jessie, spoken to Casey's daughter and got the brake shoe to Kekkabah.
He declared war on the Atchisons. I've left the RNC to the world map and Kekkabah have announced that he'd killed all of the Atchison camp.

But the mission is still not marked as resolved. What elase do I need to do?

Comment: Have you gone back to Kekkabah and talked to him?

Comment: Yeah. No talk points.